# properly simulate asp:Login's Logout function in siteMap

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sitemap, logout

just as the title says, how do you properly implement/simulate the Logout function in asp:Login to a siteMapNode?

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <%--[ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]--%>
                    [ <a href="~/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/Login.aspx"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

the best I could do is this:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Login.aspx" title="Logout" roles="Maker, Admin, Approver" description="" />
```

but this only redirects the user to the Login page. When you press the Back button on the web browser, the user is still logged in to the system, unlike when you use the proper Logout function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a Logout.aspx page, which terminates the user's session and then redirects to the login page, e.g:

```
Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

Your `siteMapNode` should then refer to the logout page.

Comment: many thanks :), but it works only at certain times. There were times that when I hit the Back button of the browser, the system properly terminates the user's session, and times where nothing happened, e.g. the session is still running. weird, I know.

Answer (score 0):

You need check this below condition in inside of page load event in your  all user pages

```
If(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

Now if you `logout`, then come this page form using browser back button or url . that code was allowed if your `loggin` else it's going to `login page.`

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is a way to properly implement the `Logout` function on a `siteMapNode`, NOT check if the person viewing the pages is authenticated.